# Migrate webpack react-typescript project to esm modules

Tags: typescript, webpack, es6-modules, react-typescript, webpack-5

I have a Typescript project based on nodejs, React and bundled with Webpack5
codebase has server modules(.ts), client modules(.ts,.tsx) and common modules(.ts)
Had no problems to build, so far
I started to migrate the codebase to esm modules
applied corrections on `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` to support and output esm
changed all filenames from `*.ts` to `*.mts`, and left `*.tsx` as is
tsc forced me to change imports to include expected output extensions
e.g. in the module `./src/webapp/mainContextProviders.tsx`, to import from typescript moules:

```
../common/utils.mts (former ../common/utils.ts)
./Settings/SettingsContext.tsx (former the same)
./callPkgApis.mts (former callPkgApis.ts)
```

I had to modify legacy commonjs TS imports:

```
import utils from '../common/utils'
import settings from './Settings/SettingsContext'
import { pkgApis } from './callPkgApis'
```

to

```
import utils from '../common/utils.mjs'
import settings from './Settings/SettingsContext.js'
import { pkgApis } from './callPkgApis.mjs'
```

now webpack is not able to resolve those imports and exits with

```
ERROR in ./src/webapp/mainContextProviders.tsx 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../common/utils.mjs' in '/path/to/src/webapp'
ERROR in ./src/webapp/mainContextProviders.tsx 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Settings/SettingsContext.js' in '/path/to/src/webapp'
ERROR in ./src/webapp/mainContextProviders.tsx 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './callPkgApis.mjs' in '/path/to/src/webapp'
```

How can I fix ?